# How to detect a JAR file?

Tags: java, jar, inputstream

How could I know if a inputstream is a JAR file?

I can detect a JAR file by using:

```
try {
  JarFile jar = new JarFile("file");
} catch(ZipException e) {
  // not a jar file
  ...
}
```

But how should I do if I only have the inputstream? Do I need to write it to a file?
Any elegant way?

Comment: Have a look at [TrueZip](http://truezip.java.net), which provides a VFS for a variety of compressed/archived file formats.

Comment: From the file format side, a jar file is only a zip file with a changed name, fixed file name encoding (UTF-8) and some metadata files. So use whatever you use to detect zip files.

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html#JarInputStream(java.io.InputStream)

```
try {
  JarInputStream jar = new JarInputStream(inputStream);
} catch(Exception e) {
  // not a jar file
  ...
}
```

Comment: You might want to provide a more up-to-date JavaDoc link. Java 1.4.2 is ancient history these days.

Comment: This one does not work. You can try to provide a txt file and see the result.

Comment: sorry @willpowerforever, I did not try it, just wanted to point to the class

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some intelligent prefiltering, you can look for the [local file header signature byte: 0x04034b50](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)